# Partition in VirtualBox is 32 GB but GParted shows it's only 20 GB

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, partitioning, virtual-machine, gparted

Goal: increase the size of a partition from 20 GB to 32 GB 
I resized the disk using `VBoxManage modifyhd ... --resize ...`. When I type `VBoxManage list hdds`, I can find the partition I resized and it's 32 GB in size (just how I wanted it). But when I start GParted in the VM to allocate the free space, it displays that my HDD is only 20 GB in size. How do I fix this?

OS: Windows 10

- Screenshot from GParted

  [image: Screenshot from GParted]
- output of `ls -1 /dev/sd*`

  ```
  $ ls -1 /dev/sd*
  /dev/sda
  /dev/sda1
  /dev/sda2
  /dev/sda5
  ```
- Screenshot from VirtualBox

  [image: Screenshot from VirtualBox]
- `VBoxManage modifyhd ... --resize` ... + results

  ```
  >VBoxManage modifyhd "C:\Users\mail\VirtualBox VMs\vm2\vm2.vda" --resize 32768
  0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
  ```
- output of `lsblk`

  ```
  $ lsblk
  NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
  loop0    7:0    0 800,4M  1 loop /snap/android-studio/91
  loop1    7:1    0   479M  1 loop /snap/clion/126
  loop2    7:2    0    55M  1 loop /snap/core18/1880
  loop3    7:3    0  55,3M  1 loop /snap/core18/1885
  loop4    7:4    0  97,1M  1 loop /snap/core/9993
  loop5    7:5    0 255,6M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
  loop6    7:6    0  30,3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/9279
  loop7    7:7    0  49,8M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/467
  loop8    7:8    0  62,1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
  loop9    7:9    0  29,9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/8790
  sda      8:0    0    20G  0 disk
  ├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
  ├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part
  └─sda5   8:5    0  19,5G  0 part /
  sr0     11:0    1   366M  0 rom  /media/chris/GParted-live
  sr1     11:1    1  1024M  0 rom
  ```
- output of `VBoxManage showmediuminfo`

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>VBoxManage showmediuminfo "C:\Users\mail\VirtualBox VMs\vm2\vm2.vdi"
UUID:           9c95c78b-4016-4407-a5ae-478a5c3cd5fa
Parent UUID:    base
State:          locked read
Type:           normal (base)
Location:       C:\Users\mail\VirtualBox VMs\vm2\vm2.vdi
Storage format: VDI
Format variant: dynamic default
Capacity:       32768 MBytes
Size on disk:   7538 MBytes
Encryption:     disabled
Property:       AllocationBlockSize=1048576
In use by VMs:  vm2 (UUID: c3799a5b-c0fe-4bca-b333-21ce89dd8251) [Basic Installation 1 Python3.7 (UUID: 9732f164-51ab-4dd0-9a47-fb745d58ba05)]
Child UUIDs:    a7edd11a-2160-43ce-bea8-3e26f6563dc1
```

Comment: Please include a screenshot from GParted and output of `ls -1 /dev/sd*`.

Comment: That's not what I expected to see. It looks like the disk didn't actually resize. Can you show exact commands that you're executing and their results?

Comment: @gronostaj I added the screenshot of the command and a few more. At the moment I'm guessing it's the same problem as stated [in this StackOverflow post](https://askubuntu.com/a/737165/947315). But I'm not sure

Comment: Could you perhaps provide the output of running `VBoxManage showmediuminfo` against the disk image?

Comment: Your virtual disk has a snapshot. That may interfere with resizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having multiple Snapshots stands in the way of resizing the partition. Delete all snapshots and resizing should work

GParted screenshot showing it works

[image: GParted screenshot showing it works]

Answer (score -2):

To resize one needs to boot the VM using a live image such as [GParted Live](https://gparted.org/livecd.php)

See [Increase VirtualBox Disk Size](https://linuxhint.com/increase-virtualbox-disk-size/)

Comment: unfortunately, this didn't work. At step 4 of the post, after I executed `lsblk` in the terminal (see attached image), it showed I have 20 GB of storage in total, but if you check the screenshot from VirtualBox (also attached), you can see that I set the size to 32 GB

Comment: -1 because you didn't even look at screenshots.